# how to get function arguments from another python file

Tags: python

I have three files in Python called A.py, B.py and C.py
I wanted to do something with the following code snippet to determine the execution order (I run the program from within B.py)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    subprocess.Popen('python A.py', shell=True).wait()
    subprocess.Popen('python C.py', shell=True)
```

When the program runs, it waits for a response from A.py to receive the values in the reciv_func (a, b, c) function, it may take some time for A.py to receive the results, so I wait until the first Run A.py

My problem is that in the B.py file I have access to the values reciv_func (a, b, c) in the function but I have no access to them outside I have even defined the variables globally

A.py

```
async def main():
     
     url = f'my_url'
     async with websockets.connect(url) as client:
         while True:
             data = json.loads(await client.recv())['data']
             B.reciv_func(data['x']['y']['z'])


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     asyncio.run(main())
```

B.py

```
reciv_func(a,b,c):
    global a1
    global b2
    global c3
    a1 = a
    b2 = b
    c3 = c
    
# out of reciv_func no access to a1 , b2 , c3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access *a1,b2,c3* in your *A.py* after calling the function:

`B.reciv_func(data['x']['y']['z'])`

The easiest way is to use **return**, without the need for any global variables. For example, if you edit *B.py* as:

```
reciv_func(a,b,c):
    return a,b,c
```

You can return the desired variables when you call the function:

```
a1,b2,c3 = B.reciv_func(data['x']['y']['z'])
```

In this way, you can access the values corresponding to *a1,b2,c3* as you wish within *A.py*.